# Constructing smart pointer from stack allocated raw pointer

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Can someone enlighten me in what is happening here?

```
int* stackint = new int(5);

{
    std::unique_ptr<int> myInt(stackint);    
    *myInt = 8;

}

std::cout << *stackint; // 0
```

What exactly is happening here? I understand smart pointers when you construct them with new, or make_unique, what happens when you pass stack pointers to their constructor?

Comment: You're invoking undefined behavior by dereferencing a dangling pointer. You didn't pass a "stack pointer" either. That would be `int x = 5, *stackint = &x;` and would frankly be even worse (if there were such a thing). Your initializing a `std::unique_ptr` with an address from a previous dynamic allocation, effectively saying "take ownership of this" (which it did, and then destroyed)

Comment: Very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54414334/transferring-ownership-of-raw-pointer-to-unique-ptr)

Comment: So when the unique_ptr goes out of scope, `stackint` becomes a dangling pointer. Also by stack pointer, I meant a pointer which is allocated on the stack, which I am definitely passing, aren't I?

Comment: The pointer itself is automatic; the memory it points to is not.

Comment: what does it mean for a pointer to be automatic? I have not heard this term before.

Comment: @Iza It is the technically correct terminology for what you probably mean when you say "*stack*": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181782/why-are-the-terms-automatic-and-dynamic-preferred-over-the-terms-stack-and

Comment: Wo00t. Thanks @walnut . I now have another useful link in my favorites list. I'm sick of writing the same comment explaining that over and over.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an annotation:

```
int* stackint = new int(5);   // an int is allocated on the heap, and set to 5
{
   std::unique_ptr<int> myInt(stackint);  // myInt takes ownership of the allocation
   *myInt = 8;  // The value 5 is overwritten by 8
}  // myInt goes out of scope, its destructor deletes the heap allocation        

std::cout << *stackint; // undefined behavior:  attempt to read from already-freed memory
```

Answer (score 1):

The code has undefined behavior.

`std::unique_ptr<int> myInt(stackint);` constructs a `unique_ptr` owning the object *that `stackint` points to*. What storage type the pointer itself has is not relevant, only its *value* is passed to the constructor and the value is pointing to an `int` object created by a call to `new`, meaning that this `int` object has *dynamic storage duration*.

`myInt`'s destructor is then called at the end of the block (`}`) and `delete`s the `int` object that it managed and that `stackint` was still pointing to, meaning that `stackint`'s value now is an *invalid pointer value*.

You then dereference that invalid pointer value with `*stackint`, which causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Additional reading: [What is ownership of resources or pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024982/what-is-ownership-of-resources-or-pointers)